Reading a specific line in a text file - skip always goes to last row
I want to read two lines of a big text document with a specified line number. But it always gives me the last line of the document instead of the 2 specified.
First I identify the line numbers:
for /f "delims=:" %%f in ('findstr /n /c:"= Boot Option" dump.txt') do set line=%%f
set /A Line1=%line%+4
set /A Line2=%line%+5

than I read the two lines:
for /f "skip=%line1%" %%l in (dump.txt) do set Boot1=%%l
for /f "skip=%line2%" %%l in (dump.txt) do set Boot2=%%l
echo %boot1% - %boot2%

I checked the line numbers, line1 = 33140 and line2 = 33141, those are the right lines, but I always get the last line of the document twice (which is 33532).
I also tested to place the number 33140 directly into the skip argument, but that also failed. Even setting a lower number like 25 in there will result in the last line of the document.

This is made especially worse because you have not provided us with the content of dump.txt or more useful a [mcve], (we could copy and run to replicate your issue). In such a case we could have offered solutions which were more efficient, or used different methods, (to improve your knowledge and that of future readers). As it stands you answered your own question because only you were furnished with the content necessary to do so without pure guesswork.

OMG... its working.
for /f "skip=%line1% tokens=1,2 delims=]" %%a in (dump.txt) do set "Boot1=%%b"&goto nextline
:nextline
for /f "skip=%line2% tokens=1,2 delims=]" %%a in (dump.txt) do set "Boot2=%%b"&goto nextline
:nextline
echo %boot1% - %boot2%


If GOTO fixes your problem, you forgot to show that your code is in a code block
